# In spherical coordinates for the region $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq1$, $x^2+y^2=z^2\leq4$, $z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, why does $\psi$ range from $0$ to $\pi/2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I was given the following task calculate:

$\iiint_V{(xz^2+z)dxdydz} \space$ where $\space V =
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2\geq1  & \text{inner sphere} \\
x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4  & \text{sphere} \\
z\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{cone} \\
\end{cases}$

I calculated the spherical coordinates :

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos\phi{}\cos\psi{} \\
y=r\sin\phi{}\cos\psi \\
z=r\sin\psi \\
\end{cases}$$

$$[J]=r^2\cos\psi$$

$$\iiint_V{(xz^2+z)dxdydz}=\iiint_\Omega [r\cos\phi \cos\psi(r\sin\psi)^2+ r\sin\psi] r^2\cos\psi] drdydz$$

$$\Omega = \begin{cases}
0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi \\
0 \leq\psi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\
1 \leq r \leq 2 \\
\end{cases}$$

> I did the further computations and solved the problem but I am looking for an explanation why is :
>
> $$0 \leq\psi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Are my assumptions correct?

I have found a similar example in a book and I am looking for an explanation of $\Omega$ and checking if it is correct.

Here is my whole solution but what I need help with is a range of $\psi$ in $\Omega$ and why is it to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

[image: Scan of my solution]

Comment: Second equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is sphere? possible typo - "$=$" in place of "$+$"?

Comment: Yes, I have just fixed it. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Often happened - "shift$+$" without "shift" is "$=$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint $z>\sqrt {x^2 +y^2}$ becomes $r\sin\psi > r\cos\psi$

$\tan \psi > 1$

$\frac \pi 4 < \psi < \frac\pi 2$